# Upload a Python Package to Azure Artifacts Using a Github Action

Tags: python, azure-devops, github-actions, azure-artifacts, twine

I have a repository on Github for a private Python package for my organization, and I would like to publish this package in a private Azure Artifacts feed using Github actions for automated CI/CD.

It seems like none of the documentation around publishing to Azure Artifacts is for this exact scenario; the documentation from ADO is solely for using [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pypi?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), or seems to require manual action (for instance, trying to use [artifacts-keyring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops)). Is there some way to provide twine with credentials in a Github Actions YAML file that would enable me to publish to my private ADO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the authentication information in the project file of Repository, and then run [Publish Python packages from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-cli?view=azure-devops#publish-python-packages) in your Github Actions.

Comment: This helped, but as a follow up, I want to make sure anyone else who tries this understands that the authentication information in the project file should be 

Username = [Your ADO account username, typically your email]

Password = [A PAT with artifact permissions generated from that account]